# Are there any workarounds to reference a javascript file not in the current solution, for intellisense in VS2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I currently have 2 Solutions in visual studio.  One contains a bunch of common javascript files, and another contains a bunch of asp.net stuff to use them.  I can't merge the solutions, but is there any way I can reference the javascript files in one solution, in the other solution so that Intellisense can work?

I tried embedded the javascript as a resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930(v=VS.90).aspx .  Then I added that assembly as a reference into my asp solution, and tried to use

```
<reference path="myLibrary.js" assembly="JSLibrary" />
```

but I haven't had any luck.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this reference at the beginning of your JavaScript:

```
<reference name="JSLibrary.myLibrary.js" assembly="JSLibrary" / >
```

Comment: For me... I had to add the assembly name AND the path (obviously) ... ie.   SomeName.Common.Controls.JS.myscript.js  (the JS being the folder it is sitting in)